# gm_auth function with gargle_oauth_cache stop working

Tags: r, gmail-api, gmailr, gargle

I have written R script that download email's from gmail. I have used gm_auth with gargle_oauth_cache.

```
library("gmailr")

gm_auth_configure(path = "path.json")
gm_auth(email = "mail",
        cache = gargle::gargle_oauth_cache(),
        use_oob = gargle::gargle_oob_default(),)
```

Until today it worked well on my laptop and pc that we use as a server.
It still working well on my laptop but on server pc I get error

> Error: Can't get Google credentials. Are you running gmailr in a
> non-interactive session? Consider:   * Call `gm_auth()` directly with
> all necessary specifics.

I tried to find port 1410 like in [drive_auth() function not creating gargle-oauth token on password submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617078/drive-auth-function-not-creating-gargle-oauth-token-on-password-submission) but nothing is running on this port.
I have no idea how to repair it, and why this error ocurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me worked clean cache and make new one's.

```
rappdirs::user_cache_dir("gargle")
```

> cache folder localization

```
 library("gargle")
 gargle_oauth_sitrep()
```

> list of active tokens

Comment: This answer helped me to resolve another problem I had [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054088/gmailr-authendication-problem-in-one-host-but-not-others/75058593#75058593). But still don't understand why it worked.