# gmailr credentials randomly (?) need re-authentication

Tags: r, google-authentication, gmailr

I'm using `gmailr` in an automatic R script to send out some emails. It's been working fine for about a month and a half, but recently it failed with the following error:

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `gm_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
Execution halted
```

My code, which hasn't changed, is

```
library(gmailr)
options(gargle_oauth_email = TRUE)
gm_auth_configure(path ="data/credentials.json")
gm_auth(email = TRUE, cache = ".secret")
```

and is run non-interactively. (there is only one token in the `.secrets` folder) When I now ran it interactively, it "did the dance" and opened up the authentication thingy in the browser, which I confirmed and now everything is running fine again.

The problem is that I don't understand why the credentials suddenly required re-authentication or how I could prevent the script failing like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clean cache in gargle folder and then create new one.
It worked for me, when i had similar problem
[gm_auth function with gargle_oauth_cache stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857483/gm-auth-function-with-gargle-oauth-cache-stop-working)