# Gmailr, authendication problem in one host but not others

Tags: r, linux, fuse, gmailr, gargle

`gmailr` authentication fails, after a fresh installation of Debian, only on one of my systems.

I have a script that run fine on two remote machines, but fails on my local machine.

I use this for authentication:

```
gm_auth_configure(path  = "~/.credentials_main_mail.json")
gm_auth(email = "natsisthanasis@gmail.com",
        cache = "~/.secret_main_mail")

print(gm_profile())
```

On my local machine, I get the error:

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `gm_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
```

I have tried interactive with Rstudio and R console, with the same result.

All scripts and credentials are always on sync between machines using `unison`. And all worked fine as cron jobs, before the new installation.

Does anyone have any idea on how to investigate further the problem or solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I made it to work again, but I don't understand why, as I didn't have to do that on my other systems.

I used an answer from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857483/gm-auth-function-with-gargle-oauth-cache-stop-working?rq=1).

I used:

```
rappdirs::user_cache_dir("gargle")
library("gargle")
gargle_oauth_sitrep()
```

If someone has a short explanation, please enlighten me!