# Gmailr not validating stored token in Shiny server

Tags: r, gmail-api, shiny-server, gmailr

I need to send out emails automatically using **R** and **R shiny server**. I have used **gmailR** and the **Gmail API** to send out emails using the following code:

```
gm_auth_configure(path = "my.json")
  options(
    gargle_oauth_cache = ".secret",
    gargle_oauth_email = "myemail@myorg.io"
  )
  gm_auth(email = "myemail@myorg.io")
```

storing the cache in **.secret**. The system worked well for several months. We then had to **update the email ID**, so we removed the old token and generated a new token. This time the new token did not work and generates the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
* Call gm_auth() directly with all necessary specifics.
53: stop
52: gm_auth
Error : Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
* Call gm_auth() directly with all necessary specifics.
```

We tried clearing the cache and generating a new one in RStudio and copying to the server: [[based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857483/gm-auth-function-with-gargle-oauth-cache-stop-working)]
but it did not solve the problem. Neither the new email or the original one work with the newly generated token. Any advice welcome.